# How do you provide configuration to MongoDB with Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The `meteor` command both starts Meteor and MongoDB. How do I have `meteor` make the equivalent of this command when starting MongoDB `mongod --profile=1 --slowms=1`? Alternatively, is there a .conf file for mongo someplace that meteor uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick search through the source and I don't see an obvious way that one could pass additional arguments to the `mongod` started by meteor in development mode. My recommendation would be to start a separate `mongod` on your system with those arguments and then tell meteor to use that one instead. For example:

```bash
$ MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp" meteor
```

Comment: This works: `mongod --dbpath .meteor/local/db/  --profile=1 --slowms=1` then `MONGO_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor" meteor` then `mongo` and `db.system.profile.find({})` to view queries.